# Keep JavaScript toggle open on reload

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a JavaScript function that allow me to toggle the visibility of a contact form. After the form is submitted, I want the form to remain open. Is there some way of creating a cookie what would tell the script to show the form when the page is reloaded after a submit.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onClick="toggle_visibility('toggle');">Contact</a>
```

**CSS**

```css
#toggle{
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block'){
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have whatever server side technology you're using redirect to /ThePage?toggle=1 and read the url parameters using something like:

```
function onload() {
    var toggle = getUrlParams()["toggle"];
    if (toggle == "1") toggle_visibility('toggle');
}

function getUrlParams() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state in a cookie all with local javascript (no involvement of the server):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function toggle_visibility(id, cookieName) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var visible;
   if(e.style.display == 'block') {
      e.style.display = 'none';
      visible = false;
   } else {
      e.style.display = 'block';
      visible = true;
   }
   if (cookieName) {
       createCookie(cookieName, visible, 1);
   }
}
```

Then, when your page is loaded, you can restore the previous state by calling this function after the DOM has loaded:

```
function restore_visibility(id, cookieName) {
    var visibility = readCookie(cookieName);
    if (visibility == null) return;    // no cookie
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (visibility) {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

You could use a string like `"contactFormVisible"` for the cookieName.